# Should my application call statsd directly or should I call statsd based off logs?

Tags: design, design-patterns, programming-practices, patterns-and-practices

I'm planning on incrementing counters in statsd based of various events within my application. I have logging in place for these events. So, from my viewpoint I have two options:

1. Update the application itself to call Statsd
2. Add log parsing (such as logstash) that executes the request to statsd based off matches

I'm leaning towards the later because I'm particular to not creating external dependencies within a given application; however I'm unsure of what I'm giving up. Would really appreciate input with specific reasoning outside of personal preference.